# How do I write a string to a specific line number?

Tags: python

I am having trouble finding the answer to this after quite a bit of searching.
What I want to do is, do a string search and write on the line above or below it, depending on my string.

Here is something I've done so far:

```
file = open('input.txt', 'r+')  
f = enumerate(file)  
for num, line in f:    
    if 'string' in line:    
        linewrite = num - 1   
            ???????
```

EDIT EXTENSION OF INITIAL QUESTION:
I already picked the answer that best solved my initial question.  But now using Ashwini's method where I rewrote the file, how can I do a search AND REPLACE a string.  To be more specific.

I have a text file with

```
SAMPLE  
AB  
CD  
..  
TYPES  
AB  
QP  
PO  
..  
RUNS  
AB  
DE  
ZY
```

I want to replace `AB` with `XX`, **ONLY UNDER** lines `SAMPLE` and `RUNS`
I've already tried multiple ways of using replace(). I tried something like

```
if  'SAMPLE' in line:  
f1.write(line.replace('testsample', 'XX'))  
if 'RUNS' in line:      
f1.write(line.replace('testsample', 'XX'))
```

and that didn't work

Comment: Files don't have "lines". That's an abstraction created by the Python library. The only way to change a line in the middle of a file is to read through the whole file and re-write it all (well, in certain cases you can shortcut that but not in the general case).

Comment: Wait...are you trying to write to a certain line number or write to a line containing a string?

Comment: Your update should be posted as a new question

Comment: Are you always guaranteed that your replacement text is exactly the same length as the original text? If so, that's one of the odd conditions for which it's possible to do what you want without re-writing the whole file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have to read all the lines in a list first, and if the condition is matched you can then store your string at a particular index using `list.insert`

```
with open('input.txt', 'r+') as f:
   lines = f.readlines()
   for i, line in enumerate(lines):
       if 'string' in line:
          lines.insert(i,"somedata")  # inserts "somedata" above the current line
   f.truncate(0)         # truncates the file
   f.seek(0)             # moves the pointer to the start of the file
   f.writelines(lines)   # write the new data to the file
```

or without storing all the lines you'll need a temporary file to store the data, and then
rename the temporary file to the original file:

```
import os
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f, open("new_file",'w') as f1:
   for line in f:
       if 'string' in line:
          f1.write("somedate\n")  # Move f1.write(line) above, to write above instead
       f1.write(line)
os.remove('input.txt')  # For windows only 
os.rename("newfile", 'input.txt')  # Rename the new file
```

Comment: @NathanLim which one, I've posted two scripts.

Comment: I used this answer as it did some other things I already wanted to do like rename the output file. Though @Jon Clements worked as well too! Thank You all!

Comment: I removed the redundant `f1.write(line)` and made the code more PEP 8 compliant.

Answer (score 4):

The following can be used as a template:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input('somefile', inplace=True):
    if 'something' in line:
        print 'this goes before the line'
        print line,
        print 'this goes after the line'
    else:
        print line, # just print the line anyway
```